# Snowflake tasks that calls a stored procedure to only finish once the procedure is done running

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task

For a project, I am calling a stored procedure through a Snowflake task. As long as a task is running, it cannot be called again. Since it only consists of calling the stored procedure, the task will finish quickly and before the stored procedure is done.

Due to our wish for close to real-time scheduling (and uncertainty of the exact time the condition for running the procedure will be True) the task will be called again while the procedure is still running. This won't cause an error, but it isn't the best style. A task cannot be called again for as long as it is running.

Does anyone have experience with having a task run as long as the stored procedure it calls?

Maybe using [procedural logic?](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html)

Comment: Hi - a task will show as running for as long as the SQL/SP it is executing is running. A task doesn’t end as soon as it’s started an SP

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you have any documentation on that? It is not what my tests showed. During my tests the task was done as soon as the SP was called that's why I'm considering putting error handling in the task or maybe there is a general approach for this. Edit to add: the sql statement of the current task is call 'stored procedure'()

Comment: What does your stored procedure do?  Check the query history to show if the stored procedure is fired or not from the task.  Tasks are not completed asynchronously from the code they execute - otherwise, the ability to schedule tasks based on task dependency would be useless.